# Opa: Deploy properly opa application

Tags: apache, deployment, opa

What is the clean way to deploy an opa application  ?

Can it be mixed with an apache server, to redirect specific pages to the opa application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can deploy your Opa application behind Apache, nginx, haproxy, ..., as you want.

I advise you to deactivate any kind of buffering in front of opa, as Opa client/server messages works asynchronously. For example, with nginx you should set:

```
proxy_buffering off
```

Moreover, you may have a look at this thread about virtual hosting: http://forum.opalang.org/#0_6